# Spacy: automatically find lemma patterns in text

Tags: nlp, pattern-matching, spacy

I'm learning how to use Spacy.
Based on the example below, my goal is to get more patterns of lemmas that are often associated with the word iPhone (I have a text database where such patterns can be found).
For example "iPhone is the best smartphone", "iPhone is too expensive", etc.
Do I need to find those patterns by hand. Or is it possible to make this automatic (at least to get suggestions or something like that).

My final goal is to build a tool that would take as input some text and based on those patterns identify iPhone, Samsung abc, etc...

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern1 = [{"LEMMA": "buy"}, {"NOUN": "iPhone"}]
matcher.add("buy_iphone", None, pattern1)

doc = nlp("I'm gonna buy an iPhone")

print(doc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure Matcher is the right choise here, because it matches exact phrases. But in your example, there is an additional article. Instead you could do something like this to get verb-phone pairs:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

#extracts verb-phone pairs, given verbs and phones
def extract_verbs(doc, verb_lemmas, phones):
    results = []
    verbs = [verb for verb in doc if verb.lemma_ in verb_lemmas]
    for verb in verbs:
        for child in verb.children:
            if child.lower_ in phones:
                results.append((verb.lemma_,child.text))
    return results

#extracts verb-phone pairs given phones
def extract_phones(doc, phones):
    results = []
    phones = [phone for phone in doc if phone.lower_ in phones]
    for phone in phones:
        results.append((phone.head.lemma_,phone.text))
    return results

doc = nlp("I'm gonna buy an iPhone. Samsung sucks. I always wanted an IPhone, but I just got a Samsung.")
verb_lemmas = ["buy"]
phones = ["samsung", "iphone"]
print(extract_verbs(doc, verb_lemmas, phones)) #returns [('buy', 'iPhone')]
print(extract_phones(doc,  phones)) #returns [('buy', 'iPhone'), ('suck', 'Samsung'), ('want', 'IPhone'), ('get', 'Samsung')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding an [entity ruler](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler) is an easier solution.

Before using an entity ruler, spacy classifies samsung as `ORG` and does not detect iphone.

```
txt = "iPhone has a sleek design. Samsung is user friendly."
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(txt)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_) # returns Samsung ORG
```

So you need to add an entity ruler to improve accuracy by adding spans to `Doc.ents`

```
patterns = [
    {"label":"PHONE", "pattern": "iPhone"},
    {"label":"PHONE", "pattern": "Samsung"}
]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
doc = nlp("iPhone has a sleek design. Samsung is user friendly.")
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_) # iPhone PHONE Samsung PHONE
```

Now you can add more phones to your pattern.

for more about using spacy's entity ruler check [Using SpaCy’s EntityRuler](https://ner.pythonhumanities.com/02_01_spaCy_Entity_Ruler.html?highlight=matcher#)